# Tp command block proximity

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make a portal hub to head N,S,E,W directions and a portal back again from each point back to world spawn near the hub.

My first portal keeps teleporting and I cant get near it without `commandblocksenabled false`. I've approached from afar and realised its teleporting me from a good 20 blocks away. It's meant to only work if I stand on the designated coordinates.
I've got 
  `Testfor @p[x=#,y=#,z=#,r=1]` (repeat, unconditional, always active)
and above that 
  `Tp @p x y z` (chain, unconditional, always active)

Annoyingly this is exactly as I've copied from online and works fine for them.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: You ***do not*** need the "test for" command block to make this system work. You need only one block, the "tp" command block.

One way to do this would be to set the block to repeat, always active, and unconditional. Then, you could type the following command:

```
/tp @a[x={x coord},y={y coord},z={z coord},r={radius}] {x target} {y target} {z target}
```

The coordinates in the brackets are the coordinates you wish to teleport the player *from*, while the target coords are where you wish to teleport the player *to*.

The radius is how far away the player can be before they are teleported. This should always be at least 2, but can be larger if necessary. Note that this will also include space above and below the target, which is why it must be at least 2.

Also, make sure you use proper spacing, and do not include the curly brackets { } in the command.

This works very well, but having a repeating command block that is always active can cause some lag, and can flood the chat, so dont go crazy with the teleporters. Also, this particular command can sometimes be a little bit buggy, especially if you have it in an unloaded chunk and then suddenly load the chunk, so it may be a good idea to either keep a player in that chunk at all times, use a ticking area (which I have not actually figured out how to work, so, no help there), or have a chunk loader of some sort.

This command will automatically teleport any player who gets within *r* blocks of the intended teleport point. Alternatively, you could use @e instead of @a, if your intention is to teleport all *entities* instead of all *players*.

You could also set it up to send a message to the player being teleported, either before or after the teleportation. I can explain this in more detail later, if you would like.

Please be aware that this command may have a slight delay between teleports, because the command block is unable to teleport multiple times per second. However, it can teleport multiple players at once. You can also set it to have a delay before activating, but that's a little more complex and would likely cause a great deal of lag.

EDIT: Came back here after I've done some experimenting with Redstone and commands for a while, to give a little more helpful information for anyone coming here in the future.

So, first of all, the OP stated that they had issues with being instantly teleported away; the best option to mitigate this would be to set a button or pressure plate to activate the command block, and set it to "impulse" and "needs redstone".
A pressure plate is generally the best option for this, as it also eliminates the need for the coordinates in the target selector of the command. You simply place the command block under the floor, and place a pressure plate above it. Change the command to @p rather than @a, so it only teleports the nearest player, and ensure there is no way for anyone to be standing closer to the command block than the person on the pressure plate. Then, all someone has to do is step on the pressure plate to teleport away. Doing it this way will prevent the block from teleporting multiple players at the same time, however it does help with the cooldown between teleports because you just have to wait for the pressure plate to reset before the command block is ready to go again. This method does prevent you from teleporting any non-player entities, however.

As for setting the command block to have a built-in delay before the teleportation: you can set a command block to have a delay in ticks before activation, by simply adding your desired tick count in the box on the left side of the GUI, labeled "delay in ticks". After receiving an activation signal (or after completing the previous cycle, if it's a repeating command block), the command block will wait the desired number of ticks before activating the specified command. Please note that this number is in *ticks*, not *seconds*; this is a common mistake that beginners make when using this delay setting. You can find a simple tick converter online to determine how many ticks you need for a desired number of seconds, and vice versa.
This method of delaying command block signals generates no additional lag, and in fact tends to slightly mitigate the existing lag from the command.

Answer (score 0):

Your /tp command block should be conditional. Right now, it's just tp'ing the nearest player whenever the block is loaded.